# Colour of Radiation emitted by a object when heated up?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, radiation

[image]

I read this in my textbook and want to confirm if this is right what I am writing.

Here , we have a metal which when heated up (Temp keeps on rising ) on a furnace turns red.

After that , it emits white and blue radiations as temp keeps on increasing.

Q1 Why does the radiation emit blue and white colour when the body is becoming more and more red due to intense heat of furnace ?
Why does it emit blue and white radiation if body colour is becoming red?

Answer (score 1):

The color of light depends on the frequency or wavelength of the light. Red is the color of the lowest frequency a human eye can see,  blue light  has more energy. white light is a mixture of all colors or frequencies a human eye can detect.  So the first color is red, when you heat something, the frequency before it is hot enough you can not see but feel it as warmth. the higher the temperature, the more energy, so you see more and more colors, until it seems white, you will never see blue alone, but the light may seem more blueish when the temperature and so the energy goes up.